# Cygwin+Eclipse: How does one hide a console window in n OpengGL based program by without getting unrecognized emulation mode error?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, cygwin, freeglut

I am using a new install of cygwin with glut32 libraries on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I am trying to put together a test program in C++ using the Eclipse IDE. Standard terminal programs and a test GLUT32 program build and run as expected. I am trying to hide the console window on a release build of my test program.

I attempted to use the -mwindows flag in the linker step to suppress the console window, but I get the following:

```
11:15:04 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project Test ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Test.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test.d" -MT"src/Test.o" -o "src/Test.o" "../src/Test.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Test.cpp

Building target: Test.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -L"C:\cygwin\lib" -Xlinker -mwindows -shared -o "Test.exe"  ./src/Test.o   -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: windows
Supported emulations: i386pep i386pe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:47: Test.exe] Error 1

11:15:05 Build Finished (took 376ms)
```

I think the supported emulation statement might be a hint. Am I somehow using the wrong compiler? How do a build a finished program without having a console windows pop up in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why, but the problem is solved when I use the -mwindows flag in the compilation step as opposed to the linking step. Program builds with no problems and runs without the console.